# Matlab: Incorrect Legend

Tags: matlab, legend

I have the following problem: when plotting 2 figures, I get the wrong legend for the second figure, in the sense that the linetypes `('-', '--', ':')` are not shown in the legend. The graph, however, shows 3 different lines correctly with styles `('-', '--', ':')`.

Strangely, the legend for the first figure works and shows the different linetypes, even though I am literally using the same code to format the chart.

Do you see the error, or is this a version bug (I am using R2016b)? Is there a way to "force" the legend entry styles as a workaround?

Please see my code below.

```
figure plot(x,CR1, 'LineStyle', '-', 'Color', 'b','LineWidth',1.5)
hold on
plot(x,CR2,'LineStyle', '--', 'Color', 'b','LineWidth',1.5)
hold on
plot(x,CR3,'LineStyle', ':', 'Color', 'b','LineWidth',1.5)
set(gca, 'xtick', [0:10:50])
xlabel('Fund lifetime (in quarters)')
legend ('\alpha = 1%', '\alpha = 5%', '\alpha = 10%', 'location','southoutside', 'Orientation','horizontal')

hold on

% Figure 2 - here the problem where the legend is incorrect
figure       
plot(x,CFaR1_shift, 'LineStyle', '-', 'Color', 'b','LineWidth',1.5)
hold on
plot(x,CFaR2_shift,'LineStyle', '--', 'Color', 'b','LineWidth',1.5)
hold on
plot(x,CFaR3_shift,'LineStyle', ':', 'Color', 'b','LineWidth',1.5)
set(gca, 'xtick', [0:10:50])
xlabel('Fund lifetime (in quarters)')
legend ('\alpha = 1%', '\alpha = 5%', '\alpha = 10%', 'Location','southoutside', 'Orientation','horizontal')
```

Here is a minimum example, which surprisingly works fine:

```
x=1:0.5:50
y=x.^2;

CR1=3*y;
CR2=15*y;
CR3=20*y;

CFaR1_shift=10*y;
CFaR2_shift=15*y;
CFaR3_shift=20*y;

figure
plot(CR1, 'LineStyle', '-', 'Color', 'b','LineWidth',1.5) 
hold on
plot(CR2,'LineStyle', '--', 'Color', 'b','LineWidth',1.5) 
hold on
plot(CR3,'LineStyle', ':', 'Color', 'b','LineWidth',1.5)
set(gca, 'xtick', [0:10:50])
xlabel('Fund lifetime (in quarters)')
legend ('\alpha = 1%', '\alpha = 5%', '\alpha = 10%', 'location','southoutside', 'Orientation','horizontal')

hold on

% Figure 2
figure       
plot(CFaR1_shift, 'LineStyle', '-', 'Color', 'b','LineWidth',1.5) 
hold on
plot(CFaR2_shift,'LineStyle', '--', 'Color', 'b','LineWidth',1.5) 
hold on
plot(CFaR3_shift,'LineStyle', ':', 'Color', 'b','LineWidth',1.5)
set(gca, 'xtick', [0:10:50])
xlabel('Fund lifetime (in quarters)')
legend ('\alpha = 1%', '\alpha = 5%', '\alpha = 10%', 'Location','southoutside', 'Orientation','horizontal')
```

The following problem shows that the legend types are not equal to the lines shown in the graph:

[image: Screenshot]

EDIT2: if I comment 2 plots and leave only one line to be drawn, the style of the legend is the one of the line drawn. For example, if I only draw the second line, it looks like below:

[image: EDIT2]

Comment: Please try to construct a [mcve] demonstrating your problem. Not all variables are defined in your code. Providing an image of your problem may be helpful too.

Comment: Couldn't reproduce it with R2016a

Comment: Thank you. I have edited my message including a minimum example. Surprisingly, here the legend is shown correctly. Do you see any difference?

Answer (score 2):

The code below works for me, version 2016a, if you have any questions, just ask.

[image: Graphs showing proper legends]

What I basically did is add handles to the lines you're plotting and making sure that the legend entries text is entered into a cell array instead of different arguments into the legend call (of matlab).
You also have a bunch of unnecessary "hold on" calls but I didn't remove those.

```
x=1:0.5:50;
y=x.^2;

CR1=3*y;
CR2=15*y;
CR3=20*y;

CFaR1_shift=10*y;
CFaR2_shift=15*y;
CFaR3_shift=20*y;

text={'\alpha = 1%', '\alpha = 5%', '\alpha = 10%'}; %text is the same for both legends so make 1 variable, has to be entered in a cell array

figure
h1=plot(CR1, 'LineStyle', '-', 'Color', 'b','LineWidth',1.5);
hold on
h2=plot(CR2,'LineStyle', '--', 'Color', 'b','LineWidth',1.5);
hold on
h3=plot(CR3,'LineStyle', ':', 'Color', 'b','LineWidth',1.5);
set(gca, 'xtick', [0:10:50])
xlabel('Fund lifetime (in quarters)')
hands=[h1,h2,h3]; %collect handles sometimes easier, can also be directly entered into legend
hlgd1=legend (hands,text, 'location','southoutside', 'Orientation','horizontal'); %handle so legend can be easily adjusted later on

hold on

% Figure 2
figure       
h4=plot(CFaR1_shift, 'LineStyle', '-', 'Color', 'b','LineWidth',1.5);
hold on
h5=plot(CFaR2_shift,'LineStyle', '--', 'Color', 'b','LineWidth',1.5);
hold on
h6=plot(CFaR3_shift,'LineStyle', ':', 'Color', 'b','LineWidth',1.5);
set(gca, 'xtick', [0:10:50])
xlabel('Fund lifetime (in quarters)')
hands2=[h4,h5,h6]; %collect handles sometimes easier, can also be directly entered into legend
hlgd2=legend (hands2,text,'Location','southoutside', 'Orientation','horizontal');
```

Comment: @mcpe if this helps you, please upvote it. If it solves your problem, please accept it. If you're having trouble and need help, please respond and ask.

Comment: This makes sense, but it didn't work for me. MATLAB finds new ways to make the easy things hard...

Answer (score 0):

In your second edit, there is some strange behaviour. If you plot one line, then call for a legend with 3 labels, it should ignore the extra labels (and tell you it is doing so!)

[image: legend]

This means the legend is only treating your labels as all belonging to the first (or only) line, whatever that style is.

To resolve this, try:

- placing the `legend` call on the line immediately after the final `plot`.
- using only plain text (removing `\alpha`) in case the TeX rendering is an issue
- remove the percent sign `%` in case that is causing an issue (for some unknown reason!)
- Simplifying the name-value pair arguments by using things like

  ```
  plot(x,CFaR3_shift, ':b', 'LineWidth',1.5)
  ```

---

As per the [documentation](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/legend.html#bvaamk1-1), you should provide the multiple labels in a cell array if you are also using name-value arguments (like the line style)

> `legend(labels,Name,Value)` sets legend properties using one or more name-value pair arguments. **You must specify the labels using a cell array**; for example, `legend({'A','B'},'FontSize',12)`.

So in your case, call

```
 legend ({'\alpha = 1%', '\alpha = 5%', '\alpha = 10%'}, 'Location','southoutside', 'Orientation','horizontal')
```

---

Also as an aside, you can just call `hold on` *once* per figure.

```
figure       
hold on
plot(CFaR1_shift, 'LineStyle', '-', 'Color', 'b','LineWidth',1.5) 
plot(CFaR2_shift,'LineStyle', '--', 'Color', 'b','LineWidth',1.5) 
plot(CFaR3_shift,'LineStyle', ':', 'Color', 'b','LineWidth',1.5)
hold off
```

Comment: Thank you for your comment. Unfortunately, that did not solve the issue... Have also restarted, without success.

Comment: Please provide screenshots of what your figures look like so we can better understand the problem. Since *you* can't reproduce the problem, *we* definitely can't and it becomes unclear what is going wrong! You minimal example appears to be identical to the orginial code other than not know what the inputs are...

Comment: Dear Wolfie, thank you. I have included a screenshot in my initial post. I have tried to provide a minimal example which just uses different data points, but the rest is similar. Hope the screenshot helps...

Comment: still does not work. the strange thing is, that it works for the first figure, even without the code in your edit...

Comment: So you have removed the excessive `hold on`s, included the use of a cell array and used `hold off`s after the plotting? What happens if you swap the order in which the figures are made?

Comment: Yes I have. If I change the order, the second one is correct, whereas the other one is still as before...

Comment: I suggest removing surplus lines (like the second and third `plot` and corresponding legend entries, the `xtick` and `xlabel` lines) one by one until the issue is resolved, then work back up to pinpoint which line introduces the error.

Comment: Thank you! See the screenshot in my edit 2. The legend strangely adapts to the plot I am drawing...

Comment: All good ideas, none works... if I try simplifying the name-value pair arguments, I get an error: Error in Function (line 200)
plot(x, CFaR3_shift,'LineStyle', ':b', 'LineWidth',1.5)

Comment: Do not include `'LineStyle'`, look at my example again... are `x` and `CFaR3_shift` both numeric arrays / vectors? What do you mean you're using the quantile function to build the graphs?